# colsplit gives NAs instead of valid valies

Tags: dataframe

I am using colsplit to split a character column, which has phrases, into its constituent words, with a column for each word. However, it gives NAs instead of valid words for the following example.

```
> p <- data.frame(Phrase = c("the last time i", "given the situation i"))
> p
                 Phrase
1       the last time i
2 given the situation i
> colsplit(p$Phrase, " ", names = c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4"))
     w1   w2        w3 w4
1   the last      time NA
2 given  the situation NA
>
```

I don't understand why "w4" column doesn't have "i"s from the phrases in the original data frame. Do I need to split the string using something else other than " "? Or, are there any options in colsplit that I need to use for it to work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I changed the above phrases to "the last time it" and "given the situation it" and tried colsplit. It works just fine and gives "it" in last column and no NAs. I also tried replacing "it" by the single letter "a", just in case it happens to be a problem when the last word is a single letter. But it works fine with "a" at the end as well. So, I don't know what is happening here.